# Is it possible to hold multiple types of enums in a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, enums

Is it possible to do something like this in C++:

```cpp
enum A {//Starts from 0 and has no enum with out of place value like 0,1,5,40, etc.
    eg1,
    eg2,
    eg3,
    ...
}

enum B {//Same structure as enum A
    e1,
    e2,
    e3,
    ...
}

some_data_type e = eg1;//No errors here
e = e2;//No errors here
```

I think it could be something like just an integer, but just to be safe is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to later figure out which kind of enum `e` holds, or just the value?

Comment: Does the code you presented not work? Just use `int` instead of `some_data_type`

Comment: If not C++17 `std::variant` (or `std::any`), then in ONE variable will hard unless you wrap the "one variable" in a `struct { enum { enum_A, enum_B } which; union { A a; B b; } value; } enum_value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok losing the distinction between the original types, then an integer would work.  If you want to be a little more restrictive and only allow assignment from and comparison against "compatible" enums, then a user-defined type with implicit conversion from both `A` and `B` is probably wanted.  Unfortunately you can't add conversions directly between two enums because conversion functions and converting constructors both have to be member functions, which enums don't allow.

If you want to keep them distinguished later, then `boost::variant<A, B>` will do that.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 and later, you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for that:

```cpp
enum A {//Starts from 0 and has no enum with out of place value like 0,1,5,40, etc.
    eg1,
    eg2,
    eg3,
    ...
}

enum B {//Same structure as enum A
    e1,
    e2,
    e3,
    ...
}

std::variant<A,B> e = eg1;
e = e2;
```